# Write text from a form into a text file

Tags: php, fwrite

The script is not having the desired effect. The message entered is not being written into the text file. If I replace line:
fwrite($file, $message); with 
fwrite($file, "Hellow World");
It works, suggesting that variable $message is not storing any data.  Any help would be most appreciated
The HTML Script:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name="WMessage" rows ="5" cols="40"></textarea> Enter your message!<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Message">
</form>
```

The PHP Script:

```
<?PHP
    if($_POST['submit'] == "Save Message") {
        $message = $_Post["WMessage"];
        $file = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($file, $message);
        fclose($file);
    }
    echo $message;
?>
```

Comment: Hi MissDizy - I was looking at you most recent question just as it got deleted and noticed that in your last for next loop using **counter** as the index. Within the loop, you were referring to the variable **i** and not counter - if you changed the references from I to counter, maybe that would help. Sadly there is no way on stack overflow to contact users directly, but if you want to email me about your deleted post, please feel free to look at my profile to get my address. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `$_Post` in `$_Post["WMessage"];` **must** be in uppercase, it's a superglobal.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

```
$_POST["WMessage"];
```

Comment: Arghhhhh, how frustrating! I know this as well! So sorry. Many thanks.  That's 2 hours down the drain!! So convinced it was a logic error